# How to stop React to rerender when I switch to other url from project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I build a project in React using Redux and Router and I have a little question. If I navigate between project pages by clicking buttons, my state from Redux is not deleted.

But if I try to write the url instead of clicking the button to go to the same page, my state is deleted.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your redux store gets deleted because you have refreshed the page and no data related to the main page is present in the redux now ,
If you want to retain data inside redux even when you type url in browser without clicking any button , just use localstorage along with redux , and apply a check if your localstorage is present then store all the data inside redux else store data from redux to local storage .

I hope this solves your issue .